# Product and coproduct in derived category

Tags: reference-request, derived-categories

I'm sure this is either a standard result or false, but I don't have enough experience with the derived category to decide either way. I have tried looking in Kashiwara-Schapira's *Sheaves on Manifolds* and also in H. Krause's *Derived categories, resolutions, and Brown representability*, but could not find an outright answer in either.

Suppose I have an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$. Do the coproduct and product operations in $\mathcal{A}$ induce coproducts and products in the derived bounded category $\mathcal{D}^b(\mathcal{A})$? More precisely, if I have two complexes $K_1, K_2 \in \mathcal{C}(\mathcal{A})$, I can form new complexes $K_1 \oplus K_2, K_1 \times K_2$ by applying the coproduct and product gradewise. Do these constructions descend to the derived bounded category and are they coproducts/products there?

**EDIT:**

As the comments pointed out, these constructions do descend to the derived category because they respect quasi-isomorphisms. However, it is not obvious to me that they still satisfy the appropriate universal properties, so that they are actually still coproducts and products. For example, my understanding is that there are `more' morphisms in the derived category, so how do we know that the morphism induced by the coproduct in $\mathcal{A}$ is the unique one to make the coproduct diagram in $\mathcal{D}^b(\mathcal{A})$ commute?

Since I was asking about the bounded derived category, I think we have no hope of getting arbitrary products and coproducts, so I am willing to restrict myself to finite products/coproducts. Since finite products and coproducts in the abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ are the same, this should hopefully mean we only need to consider products or coproducts, but not both. Ideally the argument for products would be dual to that for coproducts, but I have so little intuition for the derived category that I cannot tell.

Comment: Yes, because they respect quasi-isomorphisms in $Ch^b(\mathcal A)$

Comment: It all boils down to the fact that $\mathcal{A}$ and, as a consequence, $C(\mathcal{A})$ and $D(\mathcal{A})$ are additive, therefore they have *finite* products and coproducts and they agree. By Maxim's remark, in $D(\mathcal{A})$ they can be computed by the ones in $C(\mathcal{A})$.